# ls -l shows symlinked directory with two trailing slashes

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, ls

I just copied my `~/.config` directory to another and symlinked it back to `$HOME`.

When I run `ls -l` this shows up like this with the double slash at the end:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lud  lud     22 Jul 23 20:25 .config -> /home/lud/dots/config//
```

I cannot remember if I have seen this before.
I looked at another symlinked directory to see if the same thing is happening everywhere, but the other symlinked directory only has one backslash at the end.

The symlink works. Doesn't seem like anything is broken. I'm just wondering if the extra slash means anything, or if it's even supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an alias that maps `ls` to `ls -F`, it will suffix all file names according to their type.

When this option is enabled, all paths to directories are suffixed with a `/`. So if the symlink's target path already has one trailing backslash stored, you'll see two.

Comment: To see if it's the case, list your aliases with `alias -p`.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271) defines:

> 3.271 Pathname
>
> […] A pathname can optionally contain one or more trailing `<slash>` characters. Multiple successive `<slash>` characters are considered to be the same as one `<slash>`, except for the case of exactly two leading `<slash>` characters.

Each one of these symlinks should work:

```
.config -> /home/lud/dots/config//
.config -> /home/lud/dots/config/
.config -> /home/lud/dots/config
```

(Although if `/home/lud/dots/config` was a file, only the last path would make a valid symlink).

Your symlink is what it is because it was created this way (unless [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1342674/432690) applies). You apparently gave the target path with two trailing slashes and it happens to be a valid path. Note you can link to almost anything; this command

```
ln -s path/that//may///not/exist/foo//// baz
```

will create a symlink

```
baz -> path/that//may///not/exist/foo////
```

The symlink itself will most likely be broken because you don't have a directory `foo/` at this path. The target's existence matters when you try to use the symlink, it doesn't matter for `ln -s` though. If `path/that/may/not/exist/foo/` exists, the symlink will work.